# Accordion in ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, accordion, ngfor

I have an ngFor and for each item i have a button to show some extra details (I'm using bootstrap accordion).
My problem is that i want to open only the accordion regarding the current item (not all).

I will show you what i tried with the index but it's not working.

That's my ngFor:

```
<ul *ngFor="let star of stars; index as i;">
...
</ul
```

This is my button:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" attr.[data-target]="'collapse' + i" aria-expanded="false"></button>
```

This is the accordion:

```
<div class="collapse" [id]="'collapse' + i">
<div class="card card-body">
...
```

This is my error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'attr.[data-target]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="collapse" [attr.id]="'collapse' + i">

<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="false"></button>
```

if this is not what you want, then it would be nice to have a stackblitz :-)

see: [Attribute, class, and style bindings](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings)

Comment: I've edited my question with the error. The problem is with data-target

Comment: [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i"

Comment: I think that a # was missing